# how to use database field as attribute value in rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, erb

I basically want to do this:

```
<% @videos.each do |vid| %>

  <div id=vid.location>

...
<% end %>
```

how do I evaluate vid.locaion and use it as the id attribute?

i've tried the above, `id="#{vid.location}"` and `id="<% vid.location %>"` (the last one with and without quotes.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy,

```
<div id="<%= vid.location %>">
```

Your first attempt was wrong as you're still in markup - not ruby.  In the last one you used `<%` rather than `<%=`, so while it was evaluating the getter, it just didn't present it to your view.

Comment: Note that the only change is adding the `=` in `<%=` - `=` is needed to actually output the variable.

Comment: i just hit the delete button on this question bc i just figured it out. you get the +1 and accept for fast typing ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Also just added some clarification but Karpie beat me to it :)

Comment: yeah the `=` gets me just about every time. I'll spend a couple minutes wondering why something is "displaying" of course in this case it's not displaying to the browser but to the template itself. I guess that means it's anytime you want to "display" into the final html?

Comment: the `<%=` just writes the output of whatever code you write in. If you wrote an `if` statement, it'll return true/false.